# How filter data in R based on Variable Value

Tags: r

I have a value stored in a variable. Now I want to apply filter on a column in a data frame with the value stored in variable which I already defined.

Ex: CFIN = "Cost Centre"

```
df <- filter(df, df$CFIN_Domain == CFIN)
```

But this code is throwing below error message
Error: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Can Someone please help me with how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: (Deleted my previous comments.) This suggests `df` is not a `data.frame` like you think it is. What does `class(df)` return?

Comment: Honestly, I think I know the answer to that ... it likely returns `"numeric"`. Go back in your code and try to find where you replace the value of `df` with a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you question correctly. What about just defining a new dataframe?

`df2 <- df[df$CFIN_Domain == "CFIN",]`